# Making a tile - On hover changes the width of the tile & overflow doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to make a card, just like the one made here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade .. so I used only 3 divs, a parent div, a front div and details div. I wanted when I hover on the parent div, to show the details div. However, the details div's content will be more than the parent's div height, so I want to show a scroll when I hover. I could achieve this with parent:hover then set overflow auto, but I am having the issue that the width of the parent is increased, and it doesn't look right when it's done, plus, the content when shown/hidden doesn't seem seamless if I remove overflow: hidden on the tile itself.

Also, if I set the overflow to be hidden by default, so the page's scroll doesn't appear by default, if I hover on the parent, the scroll will appear inside, then if I scroll down in the details and move the mouse out, the tile will disappear.

Here's my code:

```css
*{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  margin-left: 10px; 
  margin-top: 10px; 
}
.tile img{
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0; 
  max-height: 300px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #008cba;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.tile:hover .details {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.tile:hover {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="tile">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
    <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that g      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
uyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="tile">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h1>John Doe</h1> 
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that g      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>

  </div>



</div>
```

So briefly I have these 3 problems:

1- When hovering on the tile, the scrollbar appears and it doesn't appear within the tile itself, so it changes the width and pushes other tiles around.

2- When hovering on a tile, and scrolling down, then move the mouse out, the tile disappears because of the overflow: hidden.

3- If I decide to remove the overflow property from the tile, it will have a glitch when moving the mouse in/out and the content will appear for a second over other tiles when moving the mouse?

How do I implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you need. I documented the changes in the CSS

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tile img {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #008cba;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  max-height: 300px; /* Specify max-height identical to .tile */
}

.tile:hover .details {
  opacity: 0.9;
  overflow: auto; /* Add overflow to .details instead of .tile */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that g
        <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe
          love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love
          that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
        <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe
          love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love
          that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
        uyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that
        guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy, We love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe
        love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love
        that guyWe love that guyWe love that guyWe love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Gerard.